# How to add UIActivityIndicatorView as UITextField’s rightView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, uiactivityindicatorview

To make the UIActivityIndicatorView the left view, all I do is

```
  searchField.leftView = self.progressIndicator;
```

but if I change leftView to rightView then the indicator does not show. How might I fix this problem?

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the `UITextField`'s rightViewMode to always visible when you initialise it.

```
searchField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: `searchField.rightViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always` for those who need it in Swift 5.4

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.4 +**

```
searchField.rightViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
```